# Posting data and retrieving with JSON and Javascript in one script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-framework-7

How do I combine script 1 and script 2 to achieve my objective of sending data as well as one script.

The idea is to have the fresh content anytime a post is sent. I am using this with Framework7. Both scripts already work well in their roles to post or retrieve data.

This is the script that is getting/fetching data from the back-end.

**SCRIPT 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "http://localhost/integration/json.php";
        $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                var comment = field.comment;
                var user = field.user;
                var post_time = field.post_time;
                $("#listview").append("<tr class='even gradeA' width = '30px'><td>"+comment+"</td><td>"+user+"-"+post_time+"</td></tr>");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**SCRIPT 2**
The role of script 2 is to post data to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#insert").click(function() {
                var comment = $("#comment").val();
                var user = $("#user").val();
                var ip = $("#ip").val();
                var dataString = "comment=" + comment + "&user=" + user + "&ip=" + ip + "&insert=";
                if ($.trim(comment).length > 0 & $.trim(user).length > 0 & $.trim(ip).length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/integration/insert.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#insert").val('Connecting...');
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data == "success") {
                            alert("Successfully submitted");
                            $("#insert").val('submit');

                        } else if (data == "error") {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
                return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Both scripts are working independently.

Comment: Put both code inside one `$(document).ready(function(){..})`

Comment: Tried it. Seems there is a problem with submitting the data in the success: loop

Comment: you said that both are working fine?

Comment: Independently they are working. I am not too sure why the submission keeps at "connnecting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code:

Here is what I have done. I have converted it into a function which you can call once your insertion code has been completed and also can be called when the page is refreshed.

```js
function getUpdatedData() {
  var url = "http://localhost/integration/json.php";
  $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      var comment = field.comment;
      var user = field.user;
      var post_time = field.post_time;
      $("#listview").append("<tr class='even gradeA' width = '30px'><td>" + comment + "</td><td>" + user + "-" + post_time + "</td></tr>");
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getUpdatedData();
  $("#insert").on('click', function() {
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var user = $("#user").val();
    var ip = $("#ip").val();
    var dataString = "comment=" + comment + "&user=" + user + "&ip=" + ip + "&insert=";
    if ($.trim(comment).length > 0 & $.trim(user).length > 0 & $.trim(ip).length > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/integration/insert.php",
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
          $("#insert").val('Connecting...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == "success") {
            alert("Successfully submitted");
            $("#insert").val('submit');
            getUpdatedData();

          } else if (data == "error") {
            alert("error");
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems not to be working because its not exiting the data submissionsuccess: function(data) {
          if (data == "success") {
            alert("Successfully submitted");
            $("#insert").val('submit');
            getUpdatedData();

          } else if (data == "error") {
            alert("error");
          }

Comment: What error are you getting in the console? Is the function getting called?

Comment: There is no error but the submit button keeps on "connecting". The console shows [jquery.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/integration/insert.php".]

Comment: Ok, it bit unclear. Firstly, since everything is on your local, you don't need to give `http://` Just use `integration/insert.php` in your AJAX. You can remove `crossDomain: true, cache: false,` from the AJAX function. Secondly, in your PHP files, do a simple `<?php echo "Hello"; ?>` and see if that works. Put `console.log()` in your JS at various points, like click, success, error, to understand where it breaks.